# Java Web application Displaying data from SQL join

Tags: java, database, jsp, web-applications

I have two db tables.  One table contains Forecast data.  The second table contains Actual data.  I have two javabeans that represent each of these tables.

I want a jsp view (JSTL/EL) that lists the forcasted data, the actual data and then delta between the two in groups of weekly dates, such as this:

```
                              1/1/11                    1/8/11
 CONTRACT   LineCode     Forecast Actual Delta    Forecast Actual Delta 
   B&M       E12-C         12       11    1           25       10    15
   B&M       E11-D         10       15   -5           20       20     0
   Smig      XX2-12        Null     10   -10          20       20     0
   Cartri    WW0-E         etc...
```

Should I create a 3rd javabean that represents the view above from a SQL JOIN and do all the math in servlets (Or possibly in the SQL itself)?

Or do I pass the two beans and do the math in the jsp view?  If I do the latter, I'm not sure how to do the looping efficiently with jstl.  The two db tables may not have the exact same order or number of rows (as seen with the Null value in the SMIG contract above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order of preference:

1) Do it in the database,

2) Do it in a POD (JavaBean)

3) (A **distant** third) Do it in the JSP.

Comment: @EFH, OK, so if I do it [the calculations] in the db, then you are suggesting I need a third javabaean, correct?

Comment: Yes, I vote for doing the math in the database, and then having a simple view JavaBean to hold the result of the query.

Comment: I'm having a hard time performing the calculations in the DB.  My example above is very simplistic.  Managment wants all kinds of agregates and rollup summaries.  Plus I need to do a Oracle Full Outer Join and even with using DISTINCT, I still get duplicate rows.  I'm thinking I should do to separate sql queries and then in the servlet loop through both sets and perform the gap analysis.

Comment: Sometimes it's too hard to do in the DB, so that's when you move on to number two in the list. No big shame, no reason to knock yourself out if it's impossible.

Comment: Oracle 11g has a new function PIVOT.  I will investigate to try an keep most of the work in the query.  My jsp views are getting out of control trying to do the aggregate calculations using EL/JSTL